# LinkedIn - Is ClientID value need to be secured?

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

When i am setting up a new application it says near the Client ID value: "Your Client ID. Copy and keep it secure".

As per my understanding, i should specify this value inside my javascript functions so its not so secured.

Am i missing something here? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are correct. It is the combination of both Client ID and Client secret that you need to keep secure.

Comment: What is the reason of Client secret? Should i use it somehow?

Comment: You will need both if you access the API server side.